Formbuilder: When using the multiple option for a new contact, only the first one gets added event registration
I posted my issue on the Civi Lab: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5616 two week ago, but I have no answer yet.
So I try here: I'm trying to do a form for parents to sign in their children for a summer camp. In FormBuilder, I set the option to repeat the fielset for a new Child contact. I added a relationship to the Parent, a registration to the event SummerCamp1 and aregistration to a group.
I fill the form with multiple children. It works, all children have a relationships with Parent1, but only the first of the Form gets the event and group registration.
Does any one know if this is a bug of Civi or if I'm missing something?
You can check the form here: https://lajoiedevivre.net/inscriptions25/
